# Use php to set cron job

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to make a "generic" way of setting cron jobs because I'm making a commercial system and it needs to work for everyone.

This is what I'm doing:

```
<?php
$data = '0 0,12 * * * -q /public_html/currency.php ';
file_put_contents('cron.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
exec('sudo crontab cron.txt', $output, $return);
if($return === 0)
{
  echo 'Cron Successful';
  } else {
  echo 'Cron Unsuccessful' . $output;
}
?>
```

And I'm getting an error: Cron UnsuccessfulArray

Why am I getting this error? The cron.txt contains all everything written in `$data`.

Comment: Do a `print_r($output)` to see the actual messages it returns

Comment: the actual message with that is `Array ( )`

Comment: Ah, then there is no (regular) output. Looking at your command - the `sudo` is going to expect you to input a password, isn't it? You'd have to pipe that in. (It's not a terribly good practice but I assume you know that)

Comment: Can the web server user sudo? I would consider that a MAJOR security issue if so. Anyone who gets the ability (through hack or standard user account) to run a php script would be able to elevate their permissions to root at that point. Also, sudo usually requires a password to be entered.

Comment: I actually don't know. As I'm looking to make this generic, I assume default setting is no, so can we go with that? I was just trying to figure how to load the cron from the php itself, but yeah sudo might be an issue.

@Pekka웃 just figured that lol

Comment: What do you mean by 'it needs to work for everyone?' Are you trying to  update, insert or delete some data regularly based on users output? Why not running a script each minute (the finest granularity you might have some benefits from using cron tasks) and triggering some actions depending on information stored in a data store? It's pretty basic but it might work just fine depending on your need. Later on, you might figure a library like https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib would appropriate to run some even more robust messaging operations (take a look at http://www.rabbitmq.com).

Answer (score 0):

The `$output` variable is passed as a PHP array reference to the `exec` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

To cast this array to a string, you might want to use a function like `print_r` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) as in the next example:

```
if ($return === 0) {
  $message = 'Cron Successful';
} else {
  $message = 'Cron Unsuccessful' . print_r($output, true);
}
```

As suggested in the comments,  for security concerns, it is not recommended to leave the web server user among the sudoers.

Comment: Yeah I've removed it completely, and end users will simply have to add one cron job.

Answer (score 0):

First your question: you aren't getting the results you want because the user you are actually executing this PHP code on doesn't (and thankfully so too) have sudo access.  To "fix" this issue open up your shell and instead of running a simple: php example.php, run this: sudo php example.php.  That should make it work.

However I would strongly recommend you rethink the problem you are trying to solve.  I see you're automating as much as you can (a good thing), maybe use a shell script to set-up your environment instead.  You can then even store that shell script in your git/svn repository.

Comment: I was trying to remove the hassle for end users while installing the system, but I've decided to attach a tutorial how to add a cronjob and  pull all my cron jobs into 1 file, to make it easier. I'm far away from shell scripting, so maybe in a future update I'll re-think this. For now, user will have to go through the hassle of adding 1 cron task on their own.